# Specifying non-local time zone in GlobalConfiguration fails on Linux

Tags: atata

My tests will be running on a variety of machines/containers scattered all across the USA, so I would like them all to log their time in Eastern Time.  If I do this:

```
AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration.UseTimeZone(System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"))
```

All my logs generated by Windows machines work fine, but in linux (Debian 11) I get this:

```
  Error Message:
   OneTimeSetUp: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException : The time zone ID 'Eastern Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Eastern Standard Time'.
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the time zone synced across all logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is correct. You can find a time zone by different names depending on current OS. But in addition to that here is another solution.

You can add `TimeZoneConverter` NuGet package to a project and use its `TZConvert` class to find a time zone by either Windows or Linux time zone ID.

```
AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration.UseTimeZone(TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("US/Eastern"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```html
using System;

TimeZoneInfo ET;
    
if (WebDriverSetup.OSInfo.IsWindows)
{
    ET = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
}
else
{
    ET = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US/Eastern");
}

AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration.UseTimeZone(ET);
```